# Shoes to wear for December trip to Europe

Tags: europe, clothing, winter

I will be in travelling to Europe in December around new year and expecting temperatures in the range of -10 to 5 degree centigrade along with Rain.

So i am looking for some water proof shoes which will also be warm but when i search online i can only see Hiking or snow shoes which seem to be quite bulky.

I will be spending time in cities mainly, so i don't need something which look suitable for going to pubs, bars, restaurants.

Can someone please advise what should i go for.

EDIT:

I will be travelling to Berlin, Prague and have booked some tours in Iceland including glacier walks. For glacier walks i plan to rent snow hiking shoes but if same are suitable for cities then i can probably buy them

Comment: What cities are you going to?

Comment: @MarkPerryman : See my edit in question, i have added cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For urban tourism in Berlin and Prague it's unlikely that you'll need to deal with anything worse than a centimeter or two of half-melted slush lying in the street. Any pair of rubber-soled closed-toed shoes should do for that -- especially if they are new enough to have a few millimeters of tread left for slipping resistance.

Apart from having rubber soles, seeking something explicitly marketed as "waterproof" would strike me as overkill. For keeping warm, you may wish to go for trainers with padded uppers, or better yet fabric-lined leather uppers. Plain leather uppers can work fine too, but depending on how cold-sensitive you are (and how long periods you will spend outside) you may need to supplement them with a pair of warm socks.

In any case, bring a surplus of dry socks in case you need to change them out during the day.

Answer (score 0):

Some shoe manufacturers make rather stylish boots these days.  These might be more suitable if you got a snowfall of a few centimetres or so.  Take a couple of pairs of winter socks (e.g. wool) in case you have some colder weather.  A true pair of winter boots shouldn't be necessary for the temperatures you are describing, unless you are very intolerant of cold.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you will likely be fine with just sneakers having a decent sole.

However, these are great for messy, slushy weather:

[Men's Boston III](https://www.keenfootwear.com/p/M-BOSTON-III.html?dwvar_M-BOSTON-III_color=1015043&cgid=)

I've stepped in 2-3 inch puddles and walked away with dry socks.  Rain and snow also don't soak through the top.